# Is there a way to have the layer checkboxes checked from the beginning on my leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

Im currently creating a map with leaflet and as the page loads all the checkboxes of my created layers are unchecked and im looking for a possibility to have them checked from the beginning, is there any way to do so?

Im a beginner when it comes to coding, did some research online and on the leaflet website but couldn't find any answer to my problem.

in the following code, the s0001 are my markers.

```
var BE = L.layerGroup([s0001]);
var GE = L.layerGroup([s0002]);
var ZH = L.layerGroup([s0003]);

var kantone = {
    "Bern": BE,
    "Genf": GE,
    "Zürich": ZH,
};

L.control.layers(null, kantone).addTo(map);
```

Is this part of the code enough or do i need to put more of the code in my question?

Do i need to add/remove code or change up the code to make it work to have the checkboxes already checked as i load the page?

Many thanks in advance for your help and comprehension of me being a beginner !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some/all of the layerGroups to the map before you add the layers control, they will show up checked.

eg

```
var BE = L.layerGroup([s0001]).addTo(map);
var GE = L.layerGroup([s0002]).addTo(map);
var ZH = L.layerGroup([s0003]).addTo(map);

var kantone = {
    "Bern": BE,
    "Genf": GE,
    "Zürich": ZH,
};

L.control.layers(null, kantone).addTo(map);
```